# How to recompile Chrome Embedded for Delphi XE2

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, delphi-xe2, recompile

I have downloaded the DCEF3 from [here](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/). It works well in `Delphi XE2` but there is a huge problem :

**I cannot play `MP3` files** with HTML5 using `Embedded Chrome`. I searched a lot and finally found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495/chromium-embedded-framework-mp3-support). As I understood, I must edit the file `cef.gypi` and then recompile the C++ version. Now I've downloaded the main source code placed [here](http://chromiumembedded.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cef3/). But I do not have any idea how to recompile these files for using in `Delphi XE2`. Would anybody tell me how can I recompile the `CEF` source code for using it in my client side windows application?

Comment: I removed the embedded tag again. Your question has nothing to do with embedded systems (read the description of the tag). Unless you add something to the question to explain why it relates to embedded systems I'll keep removing the tag. Embedding a piece of software in another does not constitue an embedded system.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding just follow the instructions here and then drop the binaries into delphi