# Cant play video (mp4) in Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded

I am working with windows forms app and embedded Chromium Embedded Framework(CEF) everything working well except Video and Audio. How can i make it work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

you need to compile CEF with options to enable `proprietary codecs` (i.e. H.264 and MP3).

you can read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404590/7588861) with all the details on how to compile CEF with enabled `proprietary codecs`

the magic now happens here:

```
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
```

there is 2 batch files that you should update/create (as found [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40#p35221)):

*c:\code\chromium_git\update.bat:*

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=C:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=C:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build
```

*c:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\cef\create.bat:*

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_win_fastlink=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat
```

There is 2 wiki articles that explain **how to build** CEF/Chromium:

1. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md
2. and `BranchesAndBuilding` in the same wiki

Answer (score 2):

CEF doesn't supports propriety audio and video formats like mp3, mp4. it supports open formats. for more detailed info check out https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=371

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495/chromium-embedded-framework-mp3-support