# CEF(Chromium embedded framework) doesn't play mp4 videos

Tags: mp4, chromium-embedded

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535637/cant-play-video-mp4-in-chromium-embedded-framework) which is on a similar topic. But even after completing the steps mentioned in the link i' am not able to play any mp4 files. I have also tried removing the args.gn file in `out/Release` folder and recompiling the whole project. That too didn't resolve the issue.

My args.gn file has following contents:

```
clang_use_chrome_plugins=false
enable_basic_printing=true
enable_linux_installer=false
enable_nacl=false
enable_print_preview=true
enable_rigel=true
enable_service_discovery=false
enable_widevine=true
fatal_linker_warnings=false
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
forbid_non_component_debug_builds=false
is_component_build=false
is_debug=false
is_official_build=true
optimize_webui=true
proprietary_codecs=true
target_cpu="x64"
use_bundled_fontconfig=false
use_gtk=false
use_sysroot=false
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable H264 codec it is enough to set `ffmpeg_branding=Chrome proprietary_codecs=true` GN defines.

If by MP4 you mean videos with MP4 container then to support these it is required to make additional code changes to Chromium.

Try testing with these sites:

https://tools.woolyss.com/html5-audio-video-tester/
https://lab.html5test.com/codecs/