# Live streaming of videos in cefSharp.Wpf embedded browser

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have created a Wpf web browser using open source cefSharp project(v57.0.0) In which I'm able to play normal youtube videos. If I try to play live streaming videos I get a message "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available". eg link ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhBl5DiJmLg").

After researching many are saying that (MP3, H.264) are proprietary codec that's why it is not embedded in it, so video doesn't play due to missing of these codecs.

If the above reason is true. How can I get license for these proprietary codec and how can I built library along with these codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default CEF doesn't include proprietary codecs.

To be able to use a proprietary format in CefSharp you'll need to make a custom build of CEF. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495) has all the details.

This CefSharp [issue](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1479) mentions that MP3 went free and will be added in Chromium 62. However, the latest Chromium 62 doesn't have it yet. It'll probably land in the future minor revision.